# Should I be using GET parameters in URLs inside templates? (django.contrib.auth)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

I have zero experience with Django and everything that is  Web-related, but I want to make sure I'm following best practices from the beginning.

I'm using [`django.contrib.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/) and in `base.html` I have something like:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Logout</a>     
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

and in my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
...
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'omgame/login.html'}),
        url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'redirect_field_name': 'next'}),
)
```

As you can see, I'm constructing a URL with GET parameters in the URL to achieve redirection after the login/logout.
Is that how I'm supposed to handle this? Initially I was trying to use the `{% url %}`'s syntax to do it, but with no luck.

*P.S. Sorry if it seems not constructive or even not a real question. It is indeed a best-practice sort of thing, but I'm too new to this to rely on my own judgement regarding the downsides of the approach. From the docs I wasn't able to comprehend how I should be using these views.*

Comment: I do pretty much the same thing although I use URL names (e.g. {% url auth_login %}). You probably would want to set 'next' to '/' for Logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. GET parameters are not part of the URL for the purposes of URL resolving or reversing, so this is really the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So it's impossible to have just plain `/login/` in the URL, but redirect to the previous page after login? This would require storing details of the previous request object, not the one passed to the login view, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I guess you *could* try and do something with storing the current URL in the session, which is pretty nasty, or use request.META.HTTP_REFERER, which is very unreliable. Passing it explicitly as a GET param is the best way.